# Adding recurring event on calendar using sharepoint webservice

Tags: sharepoint

I'm using the SharePoint webservice to add a calendar event through a vb.net winform, which by itself works fine, but when I try to add a recurring event I get an exception of type "Microsoft.SharePoint.SoapServer.SoapServerException".  I'm using the webservice specifically to avoid using the sharepoint component, so I don't think I can get anything useful from the exception.

Here is the code I'm using to build the xml string, which is then submitted with UpdateListItems:

sBatch.Append("")
        sBatch.Append("" & Title & "")

```
    If FullDay Then
        sBatch.Append("<Field Name='EventDate'>" & AddToDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") & "</Field>")
        sBatch.Append("<Field Name='EndDate'>" & AddToDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") & "</Field>")
        sBatch.Append("<Field Name='fAllDayEvent'>1</Field>")
    Else
        sBatch.Append("<Field Name='EventDate'>" & AddToDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ssZ") & "</Field>")
        sBatch.Append("<Field Name='EndDate'>" & AddToDate.AddMinutes(LengthInMinutes).ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ssZ") & "</Field>")
        sBatch.Append("<Field Name='fAllDayEvent'>0</Field>")
    End If

    sBatch.Append("<Field Name='fRecurrence'>-1</Field>")
    sBatch.Append("<Field Name='EventType'>1</Field>")
    sBatch.Append("<Field name='RecurrenceData'><recurrence><rule><firstDayOfWeek>su</firstDayOfWeek><repeat><weekly th='TRUE' weekFrequency='3' /></repeat></rule></recurrence></Field>")

    sBatch.Append("<Field Name='Description'>" & Description & "</Field>")
    sBatch.Append("</Method>")
```

The part that I believe is causing the problem is the RecurrenceData field, which I can't seem to find much information on, mostly just examples (which is how I cobbled together the above).  Can anyone point me to a resource that enumerates all the valid values for that field or point out what might be wrong in my current string?

Comment: I no longer receive an exception, but I still can't seem to create a recurring event.  I've reduced the RecurrenceData to the minimum used in any number of examples I've found, but still nothing.  I removed the recurrence just to make sure it still creates a single event, which it does.  Is the problem that I'm using WSS instead of a full MOSS implementation?  I haven't read anything indicating such a restriction, but I'm kind of at the end of my rope.

Answer (score 0):

Also set the UID field to get recurring events to show up on the SharePoint calendar

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I know I'm answering a three-year-old question.

I've never been able to get this to work without escaping the content of the RecurrenceData fiend or enclosing it in a CDATA block. Anyone who wanders into here might want to give that a try.